# SPA with Spring Boot - serve index.html for non-API requests

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, single-page-application

I'm currently working on a webpage that should use a single page React front-end. For the back-end, I'm using the spring boot framework.

All api calls shall use a url prefixed with `/api` and should be handled by the REST controllers.

All other urls should simply serve the `index.html` file. How would I achieve this with spring?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to implement custom 404 handler.

**Add these params to your application.properties:**

```
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
```

First property removes all default static resource handling, second property disables Spring's default whitelabel page (by default Spring catches `NoHandlerFoundException` and serves standard whitelabel page)

**Add 404 handler to your application context:**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@ControllerAdvice
public class PageNotFoundController {
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public String handleError404() {
            return "redirect:/index.html";
    }
}
```

**At the end you will need to add your custom view resolver for serving your static content (index.html in this case)**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/index.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/index.html");
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(InternalResourceView.class);
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

Your `index.html` should be placed in `/resources/static/` directory.

Comment: What if there's SpringSecurity present in the app ? In that case `NoHandlerFoundException` doesn't even get fired. Server  just throws `InsufficientAuthenticationException`. And when I simply replaced the `PageNotFoundController`'s `@ExceptionHandler` annotation with that exception, it didn't seem to work. Server returned a 401 Unauthorized white label page. Do you have a suggestion for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to include thymeleaf in pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add these in your application.properties

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ANT_PATH_MATCHER
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
```

The following is optional. You might need this, for example, if you want to change the path to store static files.

```
spring.web.resources.static-locations=classpath:/your/path/to/the/*folder*/that/has/index/file
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/your/path/to/the/*folder*/that/has/index/file
```

Create your SpaController.java then write like this:

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class SpaController {
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/{path:^(?!api|public)[^\\.]*}", "/**/{path:^(?!api|public).*}/{path:[^\\.]*}"})
    public String get(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Or, in Kotlin:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class SpaController {
    @RequestMapping(value = [
        "/{path:^(?!api|public)[^\\.]*}",
        "/**/{path:^(?!api|public).*}/{path:[^\\.]*}"
    ])
    public fun get() : String
    {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

But please note that this might not work for path like `/***/***/***` (having slashes more than 2). If you need that case, you need to add or modify the matcher.

See also: [Spring catch all route for index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39331929/spring-catch-all-route-for-index-html)